# Installing Micello Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to develop for an indoor map for an area. But I couldn't install Micello Android SDK. Can anyone help me to install it to Eclipse?

Comment: You should add some information about what you tried already and what errors you get doing that.

Comment: I don't know how it is. Is it the way like installing Android SDK. @Alex I mean: Help > Software Updates > Find and Install…. URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/.

If it is like this, what is the address for Micello.

Comment: @Merve I guess you should contact them for details. I've understood their SDK is not free of charge.

Comment: Do you get any solution? Stuck in same problem:{

Comment: @AlexChengalan no :(((

Answer (score 1):

http://www.micello.com/developer/forum/cant-run-example

There are two sample applications in the SDK, “Map Test 2” and “Basic Map”. The “Basic Map” is the bare minimum you need to open a map, and the “Map Test 2” contains examples on how you can do much more customizations. Many Android developers reported success in bringing up the reference applications when they use the followed the steps below, can you give that a try ?

Here’s a list of steps I did to build the Basic Map on Eclipse “

1. Import the library
   File / Import
   General / Existing Projects into Workspace
   Next
   Select root directory
   Browse
   then select the folder “Micello Map Library” where you unzipped the package
2. Import the BasicMap project
   File / Import
   General / Existing Projects into Workspace
   Next
   Select root directory
   Browse
   then select the folder BasicMap where you unzipped the package
3. In the BasicMap project,

Right click on the “BasicMap”, then select Properties
Click Android, make sure “Micello Map Library” is selected
Click Java Build Path, and then the "Library" tab if not already there, then select the button “Add External JARs...”,
then browse to the “Micello Map Library/lib” folder and select the file com.micello.mapapi.jar and click open
Under the “Order and Export” tab, you should see an entry com.micello.mapapi.jar –  with a check box, make sure it’s checked.
Then click OK

1. You should then be able to build the app. But this requires an Android API key, make sure you are using one in the file 'StartActivity.java'.

If you can then bring up a map in the BasicMap project, then try to do this in Map Test 2, and step through the examples. This should get you a good start in using the Android SDK.